# is it true that conditional expectation Y to X is a function of X?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I mean, is it true that $E(Y|X) = \phi(X)?$

if so, how should we derive the form of X?

Comment: What is $\phi$ in this case?

Comment: @Clarinetist I wonder if $E(Y|X)$ is a function of X, and $\phi $is that function, is that true? or under what condition it's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a consequence of the [Doob-Dynkin lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157723/822), which states that any $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable is of the form $\phi(X)$ for some (usually not unique) measurable function $\phi$.

How to compute $\phi$ depends on what you know about $X$ and $Y$.  For instance, if $X$ has a discrete distribution, you may define $$\phi(x) := \begin{cases} E[Y \mid X = x],& \text{if $P(X=x)>0$} \\ 42, & \text{else.} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Hi! I was wondering if you knew of a proof that (in the general case) $\phi(x) = \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y\mathbf{1}_{X=x}]}{P(X=x)}$ for all $x$ such that $P(X=x)>0$? This holds when $X$ is discrete, as you note, and it’s not hard to prove. 

Does it hold more generally e.g., when $X$ is not discrete, but the induced measure $\mu_{X}$ happens to have a point mass at $\{x\}$?

Comment: @AlohaSine: Pretty much the same proof works.  By properties of conditional expectation we have $E[\phi(X) 1_{X=x}] = E[E[Y|X] 1_{X=x}] = E[Y 1_{X=x}]$.  On the other hand, $\phi(X) 1_{X=x} = \phi(x) 1_{X=x}$ almost surely, so $E[\phi(X) 1_{X=x}] = E[\phi(x) 1_{X=x}] = \phi(x) E[1_{X=x}] = \phi(x) P(X=x)$ because $\phi(x)$ is not random.  So in fact $\phi(x) P(X=x) = E[Y 1_{X=x}]$ is true no matter what. If $P(X=x) = 0$ it's trivial, and if $P(X=x) > 0$ you can divide by $P(X=x)$ to get your claim.